# lateinit property response has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm initializing response in init block but is throws exception :/ why ?

```
lateinit var response: MutableLiveData<List<AccessListItem?>>


init {
       response.value.apply { emptyList<AccessListItem>() }
}
```

Exception:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property response has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing `response` in the `init` block (you would need `response = something`). You're actually not even initializing `response.value`.
What you're actually doing is *accessing* `response.value`, which requires accessing `response`, which fails because `response` is never initialized.

You need to either initialize `response` in the `init` block or at the property declaration. Most likely with the `MutableLiveData()` constructor, or any other way to get the live data.

For instance, you can initialize the property this way:

```kotlin
val response = MutableLiveData<List<AccessListItem?>>()
```

Note that you don't need `lateinit` nor `var` anymore, just a simple `val`, because you will not need to change `response` (the live data) itself but only its value.

In order to put some value in it, you then need to set `response.value`. You can do that with `response.value = emptyList()`. Now this piece of code can be put in an `init` block like you tried to do:

```kotlin
val response = MutableLiveData<List<AccessListItem?>>()

init {
    response.value = emptyList()
}
```

But you can also use the scope function [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) to directly perform this operation when initializing the `response` property:

```kotlin
val response = MutableLiveData<List<AccessListItem?>>().apply {
    value = emptyList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what happening is you are setting the value to the field without actually initializing live data

set

```
init {
       response.value.apply { emptyList<AccessListItem>() }
}
```

to

```
  init {
          response = MutableLiveData()
           response.value.apply { emptyList<AccessListItem>() }
    }
```